# Python Update value in key in an object, from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm a beginner at Python and maybe I am trying to do something a little complex - I don't know. I'm scratching my brain on how to do this and what the right way would be to go about it, i.e. proper steps?

Below is what I have is a Dictionary as such:

```
[{'\id':'001', 
  'second_id':'0001', 
  'imp_url':"https://urlone.com", 
  'last_id':'00001'},

  {'\id':'002', 
  'second_id':'0002', 
  'imp_url':"https://urltwo.com", 
  'last_id':'00002'}
 ]
```

And here is my List:

```
['imp_url', '["https://urltestx.com", "https://urltestxx.com"]']
```

Desired result is an updated object that would have updated values* for the key "imp_url", which exist in the List(above). Like so:

Desired result:

```
[{'\id':'001', 
  'second_id':'0001', 
  'imp_url':'["https://urltestx.com"]', 
  'last_id':'00001'},

  {'\id':'002', 
  'second_id':'0002', 
  'imp_url':'["https://urltestxx.com"]', 
  'last_id':'00002'}
 ]
```

Note* - Brackets and single quotes are kept in updated desired result.

I hope that made sense. I tried using `dict` with `zip`, then went down a rabbit hole of `frozensets`? I'm pretty sure I need to create a new `Dict` but how can I can update an object from values in an array to specific key? I also tried using `.update()` but that seemed to work with integers as key and not necessarily words as keys. I also don't know about Tuples yet.

Is there a method to do this?

Any assistance would be really helpful! Little lost ... Thank you all -

Comment: I am on python version 3.9

Comment: Where did the list come from? The second element *looks* like JSON.

Comment: the List I made, it served a purpose to be modified now i need to take contents and insert it into a specific key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were in the right direction, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to make the second element of your list into an actual list.

```
seq = [{'\id':'001', 
  'second_id':'0001', 
  'imp_url':"https://urlone.com", 
  'last_id':'00001'},

  {'\id':'002', 
  'second_id':'0002', 
  'imp_url':"https://urltwo.com", 
  'last_id':'00002'}
 ]

from ast import literal_eval

new_list = ['imp_url', '["https://urltestx.com", "https://urltestxx.com"]']
new_list[-1] = literal_eval(new_list[-1])


for d, url in zip(seq, new_list[-1]):
    d[new_list[0]] = f'["{url}"]'

print(seq)
```

Output

```
[{'\\id': '001',
  'second_id': '0001',
  'imp_url': '["https://urltestx.com"]',
  'last_id': '00001'},
 {'\\id': '002',
  'second_id': '0002',
  'imp_url': '["https://urltestxx.com"]',
  'last_id': '00002'}]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as expected. I want to ask is there a way I can pass in the brackets also? for example, so that the key `Imp_url` in the updated Output, is as followed: 'imp_url': '["https://urltestx.com"]'  .?

Comment: can you edit your question to explain this more?

Comment: Yes - sure thing. Will update my question.

Comment: is there a reason you want that?

Comment: `"['https://urltestxx.com']"` getting this is not much change, double quotes outside, single quotes inside, getting the other way you want needs some changes, is the first form ok?

Comment: Yes, essentially I have a .csv file, and I have modified contents of a column `imp_url`, using lists.. Now I want the updated modified contents to be included in the original object's key `'imp_url`, in a new Dictionary of course

Comment: If it is not too much trouble, single quotes outside and double quotes inside would be fantastic ^_^

Comment: check the new edit @knowledgealways, can you upvote and accept if it helped you?

Comment: I don't see the new edits yet - but I have tried to upvote and can't because of my rep is too low ): , but it said I had 15 just now earlier? Stack Overflow is messing up for me at this time. Will as soon as I am able to

Comment: it is just a one line edit, I didnt take into account your rep, this is the easiest way to get what you want, the quote swapping would actually make the code get longer I guess, so if this is not an answer you need, I will delete this later

Comment: I'm sorry - once I get enough I will be sure to comeback to upvote. You really did help, just the quote swap is the last bit. I will do some research too and see if there is a simple way.

Comment: have you copied this code? I will delete this answer once you have made your next comment, at the very least this helped you to an extent

Comment: Yes - copied!. Thank you

Comment: is the new edit what you want? I have no idea why you want this, but can you try

Comment: Yes! This worked :D - You're the best, I wish I could upvote you , really appreciate all the help and communication <3

Comment: Yes - just did. Wow, thank you so much !! I will try and study this more so I understand what is happening. If you know some good resources, i would love to add them to learn more.

Comment: glad the code helped you, as for resources just find one and stick to that, does not matter which at least at the beginning

Comment: Hi @python_user - sorry to interrupt. I have follow up question. If I store List in variable*, and it is format exactly the same, and try passing it in the variable new_list (your code above) , - the list is inserted but not formatted as expected - no colon or key (imp_url : ) just (imp_url , ). Instead it is just not inserted and does not update into object as it would , if you do it by explicitly writing it out. What would need to change so that it can handle List containing variable which = data set? Hope I was clear in communication.

Comment: I dont understand, can you edit your question to show this change? if there is a lot of change then you might want to post a new question with necessary details

Comment: Hi - Thank you for your willing-ness to assist! Actually, turns out, there is this library that exists which I have not used until just recently that helps do this much easily. `pandas` - it has helped me with this step after some self investigation. I may have to come back to this later on though, appreciate it @python_user !